How to enable wc_add_to_cart_message?
I faced a problem and I have no idea how to fix that. I enabled "Ajax add to cart", and now wc_add_to_cart_message now shows the message that says "X added to your basket." I checked the storefront theme and I noticed this theme also does not have this option.
I tried this solution , but my website faced a critical error message.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
